# Irreducible polynomial in non-UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm asked to proved that $x^n-11$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})[x]$. I have deduced to a point where I have to prove that if $x^n-11$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})[x]$ then it is also reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}][x]$.

Is this fact true? If it is, can someone tell me how to prove that. If not, how else should I approach the original question.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}][x]$ is not a Unique Factorization Domain!
Thanks!

Comment: 11 is prime in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-5})$

Comment: To invoke Eisenstein, you must first use Gauss's Lemma to work in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}][x]$ but you cant use Gauss's Lemma in non-UFD

Comment: I am completely wrong. Sorry. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD, you cannot use irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ to show irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. I deleted my earlier comments. Please see Zach's answer below. It is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(My algebra is not great, so please check this carefully.) We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Now, $x^n - 11$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein, and so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{11}):\mathbb{Q}] = n.$ Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{11})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\sqrt{-5}$ is not contained in it. Hence $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},\sqrt[n]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{11})] = 2.$ But then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},\sqrt[n]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})] = n.$ Hence the irreducible polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{11}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ must have degree $n$, and so is $x^n-11$. In particular, that polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Dear @ZachL.: $[\mathbb{Q}(11^{1/n}):\mathbb{Q}] = n$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The typo appeared in another place, too.

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5},\sqrt[n]{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})] = n$ Why is this true?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out.